# Wildfly Management interface auto redirect to htttps

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'm using Jboss application server, i wanted to secure the management interface so i did the following

Creating a keystore with the `keytool`:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias serverkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 7360 -keystore server.keystore -keypass mypassword -storepass mypassword -dname "cn=Server Administrator,o=Acme,c=GB"
```

In standalone

```
<security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
 ....
    <server-identities>
        <ssl>
            <keystore path="server.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="mypassword" alias="serverkey"/>
        </ssl>
    </server-identities>
</security-realm>
```

Also :

```
<management-interfaces>
    <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
           <socket-binding https="management-https"/>
           </http-interface>
</management-interfaces>
```

And :

```
  <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
```

Now i have to to type https://ip@:9993 to access to the management interface so how can i have automatic redirect from http to https (without adding https to the ip@)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can just access `IP:9443`. It will automatically redirect to https.